# How to write a long method call in multiple lines in java in netbeans IDE

Tags: java, netbeans, coding-style

I have a code something like this.

```
System.out.println(fxJobList.get(i) + " " + type.get(i) + " " + longiList.get(i) + " " + latList.get(i) + " " + duration.get(i) + " " + startTime.get(i), teamList.get(i));
```

To follow the coding convention, I want to limit the length of one line to 80 columns. But I don't know how to make a single function call in two lines.

I am new to netbeans IDE. Can anybody suggest?

Comment: 1. This is not a method declaration. 2. You can have a single statement on several lines.  In your example you can go to a new line before/after any `+` sign.

Comment: 1. OP never said it was a method declaration.

Comment: The original title did say declaration...I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a line break pretty much anywhere (other than inside your String of course). I would recommend something structured like this to make it clear that there are two arguments being passed, and one of them is a long string concatenation:

```
System.out.println(
  fxJobList.get(i) + " " + 
    type.get(i) + " " + 
    longiList.get(i) + " " + 
    latList.get(i) + " " + 
    duration.get(i) + " " + 
    startTime.get(i), 
  teamList.get(i)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

In formatting options (Options-> Java Code -> Formatting) there is
category wrapping.

You can control when the lines should be spitted to two lines. To follow Java Code Conventions you'll probably have to use value 'If long'.